# socket.io handling two clients

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, angular6

I have implemented a simple socket server.

```
const io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

socket.on('fromClient1', (data) => {
    console.log(data);     //******* log 1 ***********
    socket.emit('toClient2', {
      greeting : 'Hello from server'
    });
});
```

When the message is received from client1 another message should send to client2:

```
 this.socket.on('toClient2', (data) =>{
   console.log(data);  //******* log 2 ***********
 });
```

The comment "log 1" prints and works fine but the message to client2 is not received. Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Comment: You are emitting the event 'toClient2' but log 2 appears to be listening for event 'toClient1'. Are you listening for the toClient2 event? `this.socket.on('toClient2'`....

Comment: sorry in my question there is a mistake. correction :        this.socket.on('toClient2', (data) =>{
   console.log(data);  //******* log 2 ***********
 });

Comment: My client 2 listener is implemented on angular 6. It will not print log2. But if I implemented this on socket server it will work.

Comment: also if I set setInterval and send messages from socket server to angular client it will also worked. @JamesPooley How can I solve this. I have corrected my misatake on the question.

Comment: Okay. Next question, is the client that is sending 'fromClient1' the same client listening for 'toClient2'? If not, you should be using `socket.broadcast.emit('toClient2'`...  On the server, socket.emit will only emit to the individial socket. Broadcast will emit to all listening except the sender

Comment: No, client is not sending  'fromClient1' the same client listening for 'toClient2'. I think that's the problem. I'll check. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you @JamesPooley. It worked for me.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear.